# Creating a thread using an Anonymous method - how to solve issue with Closure?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Suppose you have the following:

```
For i as Integer = 0 To 10
   For j as Integer = 0 to 10
      Dim t as New Thread (
          Sub()
            Console.WriteLine("Hello: " & i & j)
          End Sub 
   )
      t.Start()
   Next
Next
```

I know this is a closure problem but what is the right way to write the anonymous method for this case... I would like it to print all the numbers from 1 - 10 for "i" and all the numbers from 1 - 10 for "j".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to take a local copy of `i` and `j` *within* the loop:

```
For i as Integer = 0 To 10
   For j as Integer = 0 to 10
      Dim iCopy = i
      Dim jCopy = j
      Dim t as New Thread (
          Sub()
            Console.WriteLine("Hello: " & iCopy & jCopy)
          End Sub 
      )
      t.Start()
   Next
Next
```

Then you'll get a new `iCopy` and `jCopy` variable on each iteration of the loop.

This advice is just the concrete result of following the warning you should have received with your original code:

```
warning BC42324: Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have 
unexpected results.  Instead, create a local variable within the loop and assign
it the value of the iteration variable.
```

Comment: Burned by forgetting to use "Option Strict On"! Live and learn! Thanks Jon!